# implementing facebook search in application

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I need to design a search box in my facebook desktop application, with functionality same as that of facebook search.

> If a name say 'sam' is entered, then all users in whose name 'sam' comes should get listed.
>   
>   Same as the output of this sql query: select uid, name from users where name like '%sam%'.

Is there any way to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

you could do it by hand, but doing it right can be a pretty big difficult task.

looking at the fb dev wiki though, I just came across [this](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Fb:typeahead-input). it looks like it will use the facebook typeahead widget with whatever [options](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Fb:typeahead-option) you want. So you can gather the friendlist via friends.get or an fql query, then render some XFBML with a FB typeahead widget.

it looks like that tag is in beta and has some open bug reports, but it's probably worth it to give it a shot before going to all the trouble of doing the typeahead yourself.